# Getting Cyrillic around Ubuntu - Unwanted

Tags: keyboard, indicator, settings, language-support, calendar

I'm new to Ubuntu and I choose Kosovo as my country during the set up. That's my country indeed, but my language does not include Cyrillic symbols **at all**. I guess this is a misunderstanding that Linux decided to show these characters for this specific country.

Anyway, this is disturbing me and I don't want to see those characters on my system. I'm not saying that I'm getting them everywhere, but I'm getting those in quite some places, such as when clicking the clock and then I'm presented with a calendar. Here's how it looks like:

[image: Cyrillic text in the calendar]
(Sorry that it's a bit blurred, but I couldn't do better. Still not used to Ubuntu)

Then Skype... It also displays the date and time in Cyrillic.

How do I fix this issue and make my system show only **English Roman letters**?

Comment: Just change it, there is 'Date & Time' in the Control Center. Skype should have its own language settings.

Comment: That does not show anything regarding those Cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to Wikipedia, there are two official languages in Kosovo, so I wouldn't say there was a misunderstanding. ;-) Rather the installer made a guess with respect to your desired regional format setting based on your location.

To change it, go to **System Settings -> Language Support**. Then select the **Regional Formats** tab and change it to your liking.

If you want to install e.g. Albanian, select the **Language** tab and click the **Install / Remove Languages...** button.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The frustration came because the addition of the Cyrillic format is something unfair, but in the end, that's not Ubuntu's problem. It's kind of political. Sorry for bringing that up here.

Comment: @Aborted: I guessed the reason for your aversion. Hoping for peace and love. :)